# Old Ionic project breaks after npm install & bower install on a new machine

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I had an old Ionic project whose package.json file is like following:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "description": "example: An Ionic project",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-messages": "^1.5.1",
    "gulp": "^3.5.6",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
    "shelljs": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "android"
  ]
}
```

Bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "HelloIonic",
  "private": "true",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.3.1",
    "angular-route": "~1.3.1",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.0",
    "bootstrap-material-design": "~0.1.5",
    "jquery": "~2.1.1",
    "ngDialog": "~0.3.3",
    "underscore": "~1.7.0",
    "ionic": "^1.2.4",
    "angular-resource": "^1.5.2",
    "angular-google-chart": "^0.1.0",
    "angular-ui-router-styles": "^1.1.0",
    "angular-audio": "^1.7.2"
  }
}
```

With these settings it is working on one of my machines since a few months. Today I tried to clone this repo on another machine and tried to set it up, but unfortunately ran into errors like `$http(...).success is not a function` & `Error: transition superseded at $StateProvider.$get`. Also, if I check in my developer console images are are not loaded.

I simply ran npm install ionic, npm install bower, npm install & then bower install. After that ionic serve

What I should do to run my project on these old settings without having to change my code?

**UPDATE:**

If I do angular.version in my developer console then I see `full: "1.6.4", major: 1, minor: 6, dot: 4, codeName: "phenomenal-footnote"` and for ionic.version: `1.2.4`

however on old machine angular.version is 1.5.8 and ionic.version is 1.2.4

Comment: Hello @Nitish, I have the same problem, have you find a solution ?

Comment: unfortunately not so far

Comment: I ran into a similar issue, I can't get to run my ionic project after windows OS re-installation